# Running a database in run time version brings up an error

Tags: ms-access

I've finished creating a database and it works perfectly on my computer. I'm using access 2013 and in my VBA code I have written error handler for each function/sub which I use in most databases. 
However the users that it is designed for have Access run-time 2007 and every time i run it on their machine i get an un-trapped error "Execution of this application has stopped due to a run-time error".

Code for the command button.

Option Compare Database

```
 Private Sub Command0_Click()
 Dim ErrorStep As String
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Procedure : Command0_Click
 ' Author    : Chris Sparkes
 ' Date      : 13/08/2013
 '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ErrorStep = "1 - Cleansing Records"
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry1_3"
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry4-7"
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry9"

 Call ExcelOutputReport

 Exit_Command0_Click:
 On Error GoTo 0
 Exit Sub

 Command0_Click_Error:
 MsgBox "Error in procedure Command0_Click of VBA Document."
 GoTo Exit_Command0_Click
 On Error GoTo 0

 End Sub


 Public Function ExcelOutputReport()

Dim ErrorStep As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : ExcelOutputReport
' Author    : Chris Sparkes
' Date      : 13/08/2013
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ErrorStep = "1 - Cleansing Records"

 Dim dbLocal As DAO.Database
    Dim tbloutput As DAO.Recordset
    'DAO Declarations

    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet


    Dim IntCurrTask As Integer
    Dim blurb As String

    Set dbLocal = CurrentDb()
    Set tbloutput = dbLocal.OpenRecordset("tbl_output")

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("G:\Enliven Sales                 Report\Envliven_Report_Template_1.xls")
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Enliven")

    objExcel.Visible = True
    objWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True

    tbloutput.MoveFirst
    IntCurrTask = 2

Do While Not tbloutput.EOF
    With objWorksheet

    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 1).Value = tbloutput![CustomerOrderCode]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 2).Value = tbloutput![CustomerCode]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 3).Value = tbloutput![CustomerDescription]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 4).Value = tbloutput![ItemCode]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 5).Value = tbloutput![ItemDescription]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 6).Value = tbloutput![DateOrderPlaced]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 7).Value = tbloutput![CustomerDueDate]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 8).Value = tbloutput![Quantity]
    .Cells(IntCurrTask, 9).Value = tbloutput![ShippedQuantity]

          End With

        IntCurrTask = IntCurrTask + 1
        tbloutput.MoveNext
    Loop

    tbloutput.Close
    dbLocal.Close

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

        Set tbloutput = Nothing
        Set dbLocal = Nothing
        Set objWorksheet = Nothing
        Set objWorkbook = Nothing
        Set objExcel = Nothing

Exit_ExcelOutputReport:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ExcelOutputReport_Error:
    MsgBox "Error at in procedure ExcelOutputReport of VBA Document."
    GoTo Exit_ExcelOutputReport

    End Function
```

Has anyone got any ideas what may be causing this? The references should be fine as I'm using the same ones that I know have worked with different databases that I've made.

Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: I would suggest that you enable the warnings (comment out SetWarnings false) and try again.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made a change unfortunately.

Comment: Can you show us the queries and the rest of the code (function ExcelOutputReport)?!

Comment: Access Runtime does sometimes crash even when the exactly the same code works using the regular version of Access. It odes not seem to be as stable as the regular version.

Comment: Hmm I don't suppose anyone can see any issues with anything in Command0()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added error routines, but you did not activate them. At the beginning of your methods, add an `On Error Goto` statement:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    On Error Goto Command0_Click_Error
    ...
End Sub

Public Function ExcelOutputReport()
    On Error Goto ExcelOutputReport_Error
    ...
End Sub
```

In your error routines, you should display (at least) the contents of `Err.Description` instead of a generic error message. Otherwise, you will have a really hard time tracking the source of errors. E.g.:

```
MsgBox "Error in procedure Command0_Click: " & Err.Description
```

Comment: Thanks! Ok thats worked, apparently it's an error in Command0_click(). I will have a look at this and try and work it out. 
Thanks again.